# Use C++ shared_ptr to wrap C struct with deleter

Tags: c++, wrapper, smart-pointers

Beginner's question here: given that there is a C library with following supposed usage in C:

```
struct c_struct* c_obj = NULL;
func(&c_obj); //mallocs and fills c_struct
free_c_struct(c_obj); //my reponsibility to free it
```

What would be the way to wrap it with C++ shared_ptr ?
Tried it this way - deleter (free_c_struct) doesn't work:

```
{
    struct c_struct* c_obj = nullptr;
    std::shared_ptr<struct c_struct> ptr (c_obj, free_c_struct);

    //
    // some amount of code
    //

    func(&c_obj);

    //
    // yet some amount of code, could return, or throw
    // so I'm supposing "smart" functionality would do the work to free memory
    //
    //
    //block ends, expect deleter to be called here
}
```

At block end nullptr is passed to free_c_struct, but I want to pass malloc'ed address. Am I missing something completely ?

Thanks for your attention.

**UPDATE:**

Some questionable way:

```
void deleter(struct c_struct** o) {
    free_c_struct(*o);
}

{
    struct c_struct* c_obj = nullptr;
    std::shared_ptr<struct c_struct*> c_obj_ptr (&c_obj, deleter);
    //
    // some amount of code
    //
    func(&c_obj);
}
```

This seems to do what I want, but looks strange and I should write my own deleter (which I'd rather not do).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pointer which is managed by `shared_ptr` is not the same as original one - it's a copy of it. As a result, you create an object of `std::shared_ptr` which manages null pointer.

When you later call `func` on **another copy** of the same pointer, you change the value of original pointer, but the one managed by `std::shared_ptr` remains unchanged, and remains to be null.

Since there is no way to change the value of pointer managed by `shared_ptr`, the only way to solve this problem is to init your pointer before passing it over to `std::shared_ptr` for management.

Answer (score 3):

`std::shared_ptr<struct c_struct> ptr (c_obj, free_c_struct);` creates a shared pointer that points to the object `c_obj` points to. Since at this point `c_obj` always has the value `nullptr`, `ptr` will also always be initialized with `nullptr`. Further changes to `c_obj` have no impact on `ptr`, the address has already been copied.

The solution is to first initialized `c_obj` with your function and *then* use it to initialize your shared pointer. Simply place `func(&c_obj);` before initializing `ptr`.

Comment: Thanks. That seems reasonable. Was hoping that there is some kind of functionality to "track" wrapped raw pointer that I miss.

Comment: @psb There isn't, which is exactly why smart pointers exist :P

Comment: @psb you can make deleter a lambda so that you do not need to write a free standing function. Other than that i see no issues with this (except the fact that I generally don't believe in shared pointers for majority of applications.

Comment: @psb Yes, using a `shared_ptr` to a pointer type does look weird. But I don't see any real problem with that solution.

Comment: @SergeyA Thanks. Can you please suggest idiomatic way to tackle this kind of problem ? I feel this seems like pretty stupid way to use smart pointers to only control resource deallocation and not passing it around at all.

Comment: @psb Insuring correct resource deallocation is *specifically* the purpose of smart pointers. A `unique_ptr` would be a lighter and better solution than `shared_ptr`. But using a smart pointer is the idiomatic solution to managing resources.